# Jenkins slave agent goes offline. Seeing ssh errors

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins master/slave setup suddenly stopped working. Both master and slave are AWS ec2 machines and we have a user called jenkins. We are seeing this error:

[07/17/19 14:58:04] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to 10.xx.xxx.xxx:22.
[07/17/19 14:58:04] [SSH] WARNING: SSH Host Keys are not being verified. Man-in-the-middle attacks may be possible against this connection.
[07/17/19 14:58:04] [SSH] Authentication successful.
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.

I have checked the .bashrc and .profile files on both machines and they have not changed since a long time. Our authentication method is "SSH Username with private key" and private key looks fine. Nothing has changed on our side. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The output clearly says what you need to do:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired. Password change required but no TTY available.
```

Log in to your slaves as the jenkins user and change the password, or disable password rotation timeouts in /etc/login.defs.